# Is there a way to format MySQL data type TIME?

Tags: mysql, reactjs, time

a new React developer here!

I'm using data type `TIME` in my database to add and edit time slots for a schedule. It outputs *09:00:00* at the moment, but I'd like to format it into *9.00*.

I've been using [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/) to format my `DATE` data type, but I haven't found a way to format `TIME`. I hope you people can help, thanks in advance!

**MySQL:**

```
CREATE TABLE `reservations` ( 
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
  `name`varchar(80) DEFAULT NULL, 
  `start_time` time,
  `end_time` time,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

**React:**

```
let time = reservationsData[row].start_time;
```

In case it somehow matters, I'm using MySQLWorkbench and IntelliJ Idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is only a suggestion. You could find a better one, but at least it works! :)

```js
let startTime = '09:00:00';
let endTime = '21:08:00';

console.log('start time: '+ formatTime(startTime));
console.log('end time: '+ formatTime(endTime));


function formatTime(time){
 let splittedTime = time.split(":");
 return Number(splittedTime[0])+"."+splittedTime[1];
}
```

Comment: This works wonderfully, thank you! For my code, I used `return({formatTime(reservationsData[row].start_time));` with the function :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the format() function of momentjs in the following way:

```
moment(reservationsData[row].start_time, "hh:mm:ss").format("HH:mm")
```

Comment: It seems to give the hours correctly, but the minutes are shown as **07** for some reason... _(09.07, 10.07...)_ I tried it before without the `, "hh:mm:ss"` too, but then it sends me an invalid date.

Comment: 07 is the current month :/

Comment: Ah, this also works perfectly, splendid! Thank you, I probably put the `mm` on uppercase, since the `HH` is and it bothered me. I just didn't realise minutes and months work with a same letter!